# Linux restrict partition access

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions

I have a separate partition mounted as `/home` and everything else is mounted under root `/` except the swap partition. I want a certain user (let's call him 'user') to only have access to `/home` and keep him restricted from everything else in the file system. How do I do that?

Comment: Everything else? Including `/bin/ls`, `/tmp/`, `/dev/tty` and `/proc/self/fd/1`? Or do you want to replicate these in `/home` somewhere? Please make sure there is no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Because I want the user to have write permissions only inside /home.

Comment: If it's about *write* permissions then maybe you don't have to do anything. Normally a *regular* user can write to their `$HOME/` and few other locations (like `/tmp/` and `/dev/null`). Note you specified `/home` which probably includes `/home/user/` but also `/home/anotheruser/`. At first I thought you wanted to restrict the read access (sanity concerns aside) in comparison to the default state. Now it looks like you want to broaden the write access. It's not clear what the current situation is, what to restrict and what to broaden. Is `user` currently able to write to `/` or `/bin/`?